# Why my method is not updating

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I have three tables. I have main table called employeemaintable

```
  Fieldname    Data Type 
* EID          Text
  Firsname     Text
  Surname      Text
```

Second table called employeeJobdetailstable

```
 Fieldname      Data Type
* EJobID        Text
  EID           Text
  JobDescrip    Text
```

Third table called EmployeeAppraisalDetails

```
   Fieldname         DataType
   EApprID           Text
   EJobID           Text
   GoalsAchieved     Memo
```

Relationship is employeemaintable can have many employeeJobdetailstable
and employeeJobdetailstable can have many EmployeeAppraisalDetails.

1. I can successfully create, update and delete records employeemaintable
2. I can successfully create, update and delete records employeeJobdetailstable
3. I can insert and delete records for  EmployeeAppraisalDetails but I am unable to update.

Here is my update method...

EAppr Class

```
 public static void AUpdate(string goals, string eapprid)
    { 
        var con = GetConnection();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = (@"UPDATE [EmployeeAppraisalDetails] SET [Goalsachieved] = ? WHERE [EApprID] = ?");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Goalsachieved", goals);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EApprID", eapprid);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Main class

```
private void btnUpdateAppr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EAppr.AUpdate(cBApprScore.Text, txtApprID.Text);
    }
```

**My Question**

What am I doing wrong? There is no error so I do you think it is because  EmployeeAppraisalDetails is not linked to  employeemaintable or am I doing something wrong the update method? The idea is to have employeeJobdetailstable many EmployeeAppraisalDetails. One job title can have many appraisals.

**Huge thanks**

**Update 1**
I did debug on ExecuteNonQuery and this is what I got

```
string goals  === "Test"
string eapprid === "".
```

**Update 2**

Changed data type for GoalsAchieved from memo to text. I currently have two records in EmployeeAppraisalDetails. I could only update the latest record not previous record once. So when I close and restart the application I cannot update for either of the records

**Update 3**
Because I am using MS Access 2003 and C#, I have decided not to use update parameter on this occasion. It's not worth the hassle when SQL Server should have been used.

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of records affected.  What is that number?

Comment: Are you seeing the same issue when you run the query in MS-Access SQL Viewer?

Comment: I don't know what it is but I did a debug as you suggested and I have updated. I will use MS-Access SQL Viewer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have update 3 for my reason to close this thread. Thanks everyone for your valuable expertise.

Answer (score 0):

`AddWithValue` is not always perfect, we sending string value and only the parameter name. but actual data type is memo in access database. there can be a issue when mapping correct data type by the `AddWithValue` method. So better to give the type and add the parameters like below

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@GoalsAchieved", OleDbType.LongVarWChar).Value = goals;
```

Comment: I have changed data type from memo to text. I have update 2 if you are curious